# Why is pysound outputting empty wav files?

Tags: python, sound-synthesis

I'm trying to make a software synth in Python using Pysound. The first step is to get Pysound to output wav files. I also have a Tkinter window for the user to interact with Pysound. Here is the code I have:

```
#import libs
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from pysound import buffer
from pysound import soundfile
from pysound import oscillators
from pysound import envelopes
from playsound import playsound
from time import sleep

def save():
    data=""
    data2=""
    #create buffers
    params = buffer.BufferParams()
    buffer.create_buffer(params,value=0.0)

    #voice 1
    env1=envelopes.attack_decay(params, attack=params.t2s(int(A1.get())/10))
    if selectedWave1=="Sine":
        data = oscillators.sine_wave(params,frequency=400,amplitude=env)
    elif selectedWave1=="Saw":
        data = oscillators.saw_wave(params,frequency=400,amplitude=env)
    elif selectedWave1=="Square":
        data = oscillators.square_wave(params,frequency=400,amplitude=env)
    elif selectedWave1=="Noise":
        data = oscillators.noise(params,frequency=400,amplitude=env)

    #voice 2
    env2=envelopes.attack_decay(params, attack=params.t2s(int(A2.get())/10))
    if selectedWave2=="Sine":
        data2=oscillators.sine_wave(params,frequency=400,amplitude=env2)
    elif selectedWave2=="Saw":
        data2=oscillators.saw_wave(params,frequency=400,amplitude=env2)
    elif selectedWave2=="Square":
        data2=oscillators.square_wave(params,frequency=400,amplitude=env2)
    elif selectedWave2=="Noise":
        data2=oscillators.noise(params,frequency=400,amplitude=env2)
    
    #save files
    soundfile.save(params, 'voice2.wav', data)
    soundfile.save(params,'voice1.wav',data2)

#create win
win=Tk()
win.geometry("800x450") #set size
win.title("Synthetica") #set title
win.configure(bg="#010") #set background colour

#create string vars for components
selectedWave1=StringVar()
selectedWave2=StringVar()
A1=StringVar()
D1=StringVar()
A2=StringVar()
D2=StringVar()
currentPreset=StringVar()

#create components
lblVoice1=Label(win,font=("Trebuchet MS",10),text="Voice 1:",bg="#010",fg="#fff")
lblWave1=Label(win,font=("Trebuchet MS",10),text="Waveform:",bg="#010",fg="#fff")
lblA1=Label(win,font=("Trebuchet MS",10),text="Attack:",bg="#010",fg="#fff")
lblD1=Label(win,font=("Trebuchet MS",10),text="Decay:",bg="#010",fg="#fff")
comboWave1=ttk.Combobox(win,font=("Trebuchet MS",10),width=10,textvariable=selectedWave1)
spinA1=Spinbox(win, font=("Trebuchet MS",10),width=5,from_=0,to=255,textvariable=A1)
spinD1=Spinbox(win, font=("Trebuchet MS",10),width=5,from_=0,to=255,textvariable=D1)

lblVoice2=Label(win,font=("Trebuchet MS",10),text="Voice 2:",bg="#010",fg="#fff")
lblWave2=Label(win,font=("Trebuchet MS",10),text="Waveform:",bg="#010",fg="#fff")
lblA2=Label(win,font=("Trebuchet MS",10),text="Attack:",bg="#010",fg="#fff")
lblD2=Label(win,font=("Trebuchet MS",10),text="Decay:",bg="#010",fg="#fff")
comboWave2=ttk.Combobox(win,font=("Trebuchet MS",10),width=10,textvariable=selectedWave2)
spinA2=Spinbox(win, font=("Trebuchet MS",10),width=5,from_=0,to=255,textvariable=A2)
spinD2=Spinbox(win, font=("Trebuchet MS",10),width=5,from_=0,to=255,textvariable=D2)

lblPreset=Label(win,font=("Trebuchet MS",10),text="Current Preset:",bg="#010",fg="#fff")
comboPreset=ttk.Combobox(win,font=("Trebuchet MS",10),width=10,textvariable=currentPreset)
txtPresetName=Entry(win,font=("Trebuchet MS",10),bg="#fff",fg="#010")
btnSavePreset=Button(win,font=("Trebuchet MS",10),text="Save New Preset",bg="#fff",fg="#010",command=save)

#place components
lblVoice1.place(x=10,y=10)
lblWave1.place(x=10,y=40)
lblA1.place(x=10,y=70)
lblD1.place(x=10,y=100)
comboWave1.place(x=100,y=40)
spinA1.place(x=100,y=70)
spinD1.place(x=100,y=100)

lblVoice2.place(x=200,y=10)
lblWave2.place(x=200,y=40)
lblA2.place(x=200,y=70)
lblD2.place(x=200,y=100)
comboWave2.place(x=300,y=40)
spinA2.place(x=300,y=70)
spinD2.place(x=300,y=100)

lblPreset.place(x=500,y=40)
comboPreset.place(x=600,y=40)
txtPresetName.place(x=500,y=100)
btnSavePreset.place(x=500,y=130)

#set options for comboboxes
comboWave1["values"]="Sine","Saw","Square","Noise"
comboWave2["values"]="Sine","Saw","Square","Noise"

win.mainloop()
```

It's outputting a 0 second wav file for voice 1 and voice 2 and I don't know why.

I got these error messages

```
synthetica-C1.py:41: DeprecationWarning: tostring() is deprecated. Use tobytes() instead.
  soundfile.save(params, 'voice2.wav', data)
synthetica-C1.py:42: DeprecationWarning: tostring() is deprecated. Use tobytes() instead.
  soundfile.save(params,'voice1.wav',data2)
```

but I was getting the same ones before and the sound file was fine. It stopped working once I changed the section below to actually take user input for the wave type, with the if statements. Before this, the user only had control over the attack envelope.

Why is it outputting an empty file?

Comment: Typo in `env1=envelopes.attack_decay` and `amplitude=env`?

Comment: @simon I fixed that and it still didn't work. It said that data is referenced before being declared, so I declared it as an empty string in the first line of the save() function. I think this may be causing it to produce empty files, but without it, it throws an error.

Comment: Try erasing this line: ```buffer.create_buffer(params,value=0.0)```

Comment: You can also try ```params = buffer.create_buffer(params,value=0.0)```